# Is the sizeof operator evaluated differently for VLAs by gcc?

Tags: c++, gcc, sizeof, variable-length-array

`g++` allows *Variable Length Arrays (VLA)* as an extension. The results of `sizeof` operator on VLAs are interesting:

```
int main ()
{
  char size = 20, a[10], b[size];
  cout<<"sizeof(a) = "<<sizeof(a)<<endl;  // sizeof(a) = 10, (can be used as template param)
  cout<<"sizeof(b) = "<<sizeof(b)<<endl;  // sizeof(b) = 20 !! (can't used be as template param)
}
```

In case of `sizeof(b)`, is g++ not following the standard where `sizeof` is evaluated only at compile time? Is `sizeof` [overloaded](http://www2.research.att.com/~bs/bs_faq2.html#overload-dot)?

Comment: The parenthesis are not part of the operator name. It's `sizeof`, not `sizeof()`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

VLAs are an exception to the rule that the operand of `sizeof` is not evaluated, as specified in C99, 6.5.3.4/2:

> If the type of the operand is a variable length array type, the operand is evaluated; otherwise, the operand is not evaluated and the result is an integer constant.

This behaviour is a g++ extension; in Standard C++ (up to and including C++14) the operand of `sizeof` is never evaluated (and VLAs are not permitted).

Answer (score 4):

VLAs were introduced in C99. In C99, `sizeof(vla)` is not a compile-time constant, but takes into account the run-time size of the array.

`gcc/g++` allow VLAs in non-C99 code, as an extension. When doing so, the compilers follow the C99 semantics. This is what you're observing.

Answer (score 3):

Variable Length Arrays are a part of C99, which is not in C++. Gcc allows them as an extension in C++ using the behaviour from C99, which does indeed say that `sizeof` returns the actual size of the array (and is therefore evaluated at runtime). [The wikipedia article about sizeof](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sizeof) gives a nice summary of its behaviour.